# Using the idiom: "riding on one's high horse"

Tags: idioms

Which sentence sounds more idiomatic:

> - She is always riding on her high horse.
> - She always rides on her high horse.

Comment: Neither.  Someone is just *on* their high horse, or more commonly being told "Get off your high horse", not riding on it.

Comment: So what if I remove  "riding" from the sentences above?
Then which sentence would sound more idiomatic?

Comment: Do you mean "She's always on her high horse"?  That sounds more idiomatic.  [You can see a large number of ways people use the idiom here.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22her+high+horse%22#q=%22her+high+horse%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099)